# Render HTML (Images, URLs) in Colab interactive data_table

Tags: google-colaboratory

The title says it all, but I cannot figure out how to coax the interactive data_table formatter to not escape images or urls (or arbritary HTML). Looking at the source code, there seems to be a hint that it can render HTML, but I've not been able to figure it out.

(google/colab/_interactive_table_helper.py)

I'm able to render HTML just fine as static tables, but not inside the more useful interactive data_table extension, Craig, Marc, help a Xoogler out please :D